# after creating echo results in table hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

hello guys please help me

i just create a search result into hyperlink

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'connect.php';
  if (isset($_SESSION['operator_id'])){
        $sql ="select * from tmp_edu_info";
        $fetch=mysql_query($sql);
          while($row= mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
              echo '<a href="profile.php?id='.$row['reg_id'].'">'."View Profile".'</a>'; }?>   ?>
```

its work but how to retrieve data  in the profile.php page

Thanks

Comment: `$_GET["id"]` ? [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_GET` variable to retrieve the parameter you put after .php.
In this case id=your_data_from_database, the variable name should be `$_GET['id']`.
Then you will get your_data_from_database. After that use `$_GET['id']` in profile.php to get other information you needed.